# Calculation based on two tables

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have the following tables:

- `A` has columns `A1` (text) and `A2` (number).
- `B` has columns `B1` (text), `B2` (text), and `B3` (number).

Let's say the user fills in `B1` with `b1` and `B2` with `b2`. I want the value in `B3` (call it `b3`) to be automatically calculated as follows:

1. Search `A1` to find `b1`.
2. Get the `A2` value corresponding to `b1`. Call this `c1`.
3. Search `A1` to find `b2`.
   4.Get the `A2` value corresponding to `b2`. Call this `c2`.
4. `b3` is `min[c1, c2]`

Can I do this by making `B3` a calculated field, or by using a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access 2010 and later you could use a Before Change data macro on [TableB] to derive the [B3] value like this:

[image: DataMacro.png]

For more information, see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)